# As sending Bytes image by post in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

As sending Bytes image by post in Objective-C.
http://192.168.1.50:8080
{
"username":"mariob",
"password":"123",
"name":"Miguel",
"surname":"perez",
"dni":"12345678",
"phone1":"1234567",
"phone2":"1234568",
"email":"a@a.com",
"advertiserType":"123",
"imageBytes": ???  (Type Bytes)
}

Answer (score 0):

[Use AFnetwork Multipart for uploading the image](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#creating-an-upload-task-for-a-multi-part-request-with-progress)